# I have tried to get the same html element twice and i called the same php class to return it,but it is different

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an html element on my page. when i click a button, i want a second one to appear. It does but the second one looks different. The code for the elemnts comes from a php class. I use the same class twice.

My guess is, that there is a javaScript class changing the element the first time. If anyone has an Idear how to finde such an JavaScript class or what else could be the Problem pleas let me know. I have already tried searching for the id and class name of the element in the code.

first output class:

```
<div class="task-form-row-two">
    <label for="form-tags[]">Schlagworte</label><input type="hidden" name="tags[]" value=""><select name="tags[]"
        id="form-tags" class="tag-autocomplete select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <option value="Hallo">Hallo</option>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
        <option value="ffdsgw">ffdsgw</option>
    </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr"
        style="width: 509.188px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple"
                role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
                <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
                    <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search"
                            tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"
                            role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li>
                </ul>
            </span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
    <!-- 
    <label for="form-color_id" >Farbe</label><select name="color_id" id="form-color_id" class="color-picker" ><option value="yellow" selected="selected">Gelb</option><option value="blue">Blau</option><option value="green">Grün</option><option value="purple">Violett</option><option value="red">Rot</option><option value="orange">Orange</option><option value="grey">Grau</option><option value="brown">Braun</option><option value="deep_orange">Dunkelorange</option><option value="dark_grey">Dunkelgrau</option><option value="pink">Pink</option><option value="teal">Türkis</option><option value="cyan">Cyan</option><option value="lime">Limette</option><option value="light_green">Hellgrün</option><option value="amber">Bernstein</option></select>                        <label for="form-owner_id" >Zuständiger</label><select name="owner_id" id="form-owner_id" class="" tabindex="3"><option value="1" selected="selected">admin</option></select>&nbsp;<small><a href="#" class="assign-me" data-target-id="form-owner_id" data-current-id="1" title="Mir zuweisen">Mich</a></small>                                                                        <label for="form-column_id" >Spalte</label><select name="column_id" id="form-column_id" class="" tabindex="6"><option value="70">Ideen</option><option value="71" selected="selected">Bereit</option><option value="72">In Arbeit</option><option value="73">Erledigt</option><option value="74">extra work</option></select>                        

                            -->
</div>
```

the second output class:

```
<div class="task-form-row-two">
    <label for="form-tags[]">Schlagworte</label><input type="hidden" name="tags[]" value=""><select name="tags[]"
        id="form-tags" class="tag-autocomplete" multiple="">
        <option value="Hallo">Hallo</option>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
        <option value="ffdsgw">ffdsgw</option>
    </select>
    <!-- 
    <label for="form-color_id" >Farbe</label><select name="color_id" id="form-color_id" class="color-picker" ><option value="yellow" selected="selected">Gelb</option><option value="blue">Blau</option><option value="green">Grün</option><option value="purple">Violett</option><option value="red">Rot</option><option value="orange">Orange</option><option value="grey">Grau</option><option value="brown">Braun</option><option value="deep_orange">Dunkelorange</option><option value="dark_grey">Dunkelgrau</option><option value="pink">Pink</option><option value="teal">Türkis</option><option value="cyan">Cyan</option><option value="lime">Limette</option><option value="light_green">Hellgrün</option><option value="amber">Bernstein</option></select>                        <label for="form-owner_id" >Zuständiger</label><select name="owner_id" id="form-owner_id" class="" tabindex="3"><option value="1" selected="selected">admin</option></select>&nbsp;<small><a href="#" class="assign-me" data-target-id="form-owner_id" data-current-id="1" title="Mir zuweisen">Mich</a></small>                                                                        <label for="form-column_id" >Spalte</label><select name="column_id" id="form-column_id" class="" tabindex="6"><option value="70">Ideen</option><option value="71" selected="selected">Bereit</option><option value="72">In Arbeit</option><option value="73">Erledigt</option><option value="74">extra work</option></select>                        

                            -->
</div>
```

The php to create the elements:

```
<?= $this->task->renderTagField($project) ?>
```

the method this uses:

```
 public function renderTagField(array $project, array $tags = array())
    {
        $options = $this->tagModel->getAssignableList($project['id']);

        $html = $this->helper->form->label(t('Tags'), 'tags[]');
        $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="tags[]" value="">';
        $html .= '<select name="tags[]" id="form-tags" class="tag-autocomplete" multiple>';

        foreach ($options as $tag) {
            $html .= sprintf(
                '<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>',
                $this->helper->text->e($tag),
                in_array($tag, $tags) ? 'selected="selected"' : '',
                $this->helper->text->e($tag)
            );
        }

        $html .= '</select>';

        return $html;
    }
```

The first one is as it should, an input fild with suggestions under it. The second one has the suggestions inside the box. Even if I just copy the first one and insert it in the Place of the second it will not look the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, could it be simply a CSS issue?

Comment: @GrafiCode no my css uses the classnames as refference and they are the same. I have doublecheckt on this.

Comment: please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rqax0be5/ no CSS is applied and both snippets look the same...

Comment: I will check it again

Comment: @GrafiCode what i do not understand is, why it is different even if i copy the html, can css have a style only for the first element?

Comment: Uhm, first of all, in HTML ver. > 4 is not allowed to have 2 or more elements with the same ID within the same page. When you "clone" the snippet, the ID should be changed to a unique value. With that said, I need to see some CSS code in order to understand why it is targeting only the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It truly was an JavaScript function, but the only way to  find it was putting console.log to most functions in the Java Script files and locking, wich ones get executet when adding the first element and executing it again after the second was added. -a lot of work, but it works